# How to convert a IdentityMap<String, dynamic> to a UInt8List?

Tags: typescript, flutter, dart

I am running a cloud function that returns a javascript Buffer object.
Something along those lines:

```
functions
        .region("europe-west2")
        .runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 20, memory: "128MB", })
        .https
        .onCall(async (data, context) => {
           const buffer = await sharp(imagePath).toBuffer();
           return buffer;
        });
```

In my repository I call this cloud function like so:

```
  Future<Uint8List> resizeImage({required String fileName}) async {
    try {
      final result = await firebaseFunctions
          .httpsCallable('resizeImage')
          .call<dynamic>({'fileName': fileName});

      //printing result.data returns a IdentityMap<String, dynamic>.
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (e) {
      //handle error
    }
  }
```

when I print result.data.runtimeType it is a map object that  looks like this :

`{12: 239, 2938: 293}`

How do I convert this map into a UInt8List?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had to get the values of the IdentityMap and turn them into a List.

The returned data was not `{12: 239, 2938: 293}` but rather `{0: 239, 1: 293, 2:382}`
so it was index based. I resolved it like this:

```dart
      final bytes = List<int>.from(result.data.values);
      return Uint8List.fromList(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the ordering of a map's values is not guaranteed. Your solution may work depending on the implementation, but following is code that doesn't assume that the values of the map will be iterated in the correct order

```
Uint8List bytes = Uint8List(result.data.length);
for (var key in result.data.keys) {
  bytes[int.parse(key)] = result.data[key];
}
```

You don't need to parse the keys into ints if they aren't strings, but mine were in this case.

Also note: Returning the buffer is not the best practice here. Your solution and mine above will work fine, but a simpler and more effective solution is to instead return base64 encoded bytes. This encoding results in significantly fewer bytes sent over the network connection.

In the cloud function:

```
return buffer.toString('base64');
```

in the app:

```
Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(result.data);
```